# Send PHP Error if No Rows Created

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to prevent duplicate rows from being created. My current statement works, meaning it prevents duplicates from being created, but it always returns the execution as a success, meaning I don't get an "error" message if no rows were created.

Thanks

```
$tsql = "
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEROW = 'VALUE' )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (
                SOMEROW
            )

            VALUES (
                'SOMETHING'
            )
            END
    ";


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);


if(gettype($stmt)=='boolean'){
    if($stmt){
        echo "Success"; 
    } else {
        echo "This Row already Exists";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    }
```

I would like to **fail** the sql execution if nothing was created, which isn't done in this case. (It's always sent back as a success.

Thanks

Comment: You can not rely on the results of a `SELECT` to determine uniqueness, you need to use a unique constraint on the database itself, and then check the result of an insert attempt.

Comment: @RonnieOosting they are using SQL Server.

Comment: How about using an IF ELSE in SQL, where the ELSE query would cause an inherent fail - thus giving me the error I want. How realistic is that?

Comment: @pufAmuf Updated answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

This solution is based on approach, that you expect and raises error in SQL statemwent with [RAISEERROR()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so `sqlsrv_query()` will return `FALSE`.

```
<?php
# Connection
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pwd
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# INSERT statement
$tsql = 
    "
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEROW = 'VALUE5' ) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (SOMEROW) VALUES ('VALUE5')
        END
    ELSE BEGIN
        RAISERROR (N'This row already exists.', 10, 1);
    END;
    ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);  
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    echo "Success"; 
}   

# End
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

**Solution 2:**

It is possible to return output from your statement and then check the results with [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array?view=sql-server-2017):

```
<?php
# Connection
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pwd
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# INSERT statement
$tsql = 
    "
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEROW = 'VALUE' ) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (SOMEROW) VALUES ('VALUE')
        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RC
        END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS RC
    END;
    ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);  
if ($stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

# Row count information
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rc = $row['RC'];
}
if ($rc == 0) {
    echo "This Row already Exists";
} else {
    echo "Success"; 
}

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Notes:

SQLSRV driver supports [sqlsrv_rows_affected()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-rows-affected?view=sql-server-2017) and [sqlsrv_num_rows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-num-rows?view=sql-server-2017) functions, which can be used with some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean check of variable is for successful execution of the query, you should check it for boolean type and being empty. this is done by `empty` function.

```
if (empty($stmt)){
    var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
    die();
}
```